# Filter json by keys (not by value)

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have this json:

```
json = [{
    "code3": "ALB",
    "asset": 9,
    "biodiversity": 4,
    "infrastructure": 15
}, {
    "code3": "GHN",
    "asset": 4,
    "biodiversity": 5,
    "infrastructure": 5,
}, {
    "code3": "TGO",
    "asset": 3,
    "biodiversity": 6,
    "infrastructure": 7
}]
```

I am trying to filtering it down to this in a for loop:

```
result = [{
    "code3": "ALB",
    "asset": 9
}, {
    "code3": "GHN",
    "asset": 4
}, {
    "code3": "TGO",
    "asset": 3
}]
```

What is the fastest way to do this. I know I could use `json.forEach(j => del j["infrastructure"] ...` or something similar but I am looking to filter out by the keys `code3, asset` instead

Comment: I assume the objects should be in an array?

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106873/2570277

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to map more than one property from array of object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718887/how-to-map-more-than-one-property-from-array-of-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let json = [
     {
          "code3": "ALB",
          "asset": 9,
          "biodiversity": 4,
          "infrastructure": 15
     },
     {
          "code3": "GHN",
          "asset": 4,
          "biodiversity": 5,
          "infrastructure": 5,
      },
      {
           "code3": "TGO",
           "asset": 3,
           "biodiversity": 6,
           "infrastructure": 7
      }
];

let list = json.map(e => {
     return {
          code3: e.code3,
          asset: e.asset
     }
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Even shorter as `.map(({code3, asset}) => ({code3, asset}))`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let json = [
     {
          "code3": "ALB",
          "asset": 9,
          "biodiversity": 4,
          "infrastructure": 15
     },
     {
          "code3": "GHN",
          "asset": 4,
          "biodiversity": 5,
          "infrastructure": 5,
      },
      {
           "code3": "TGO",
           "asset": 3,
           "biodiversity": 6,
           "infrastructure": 7
      }
];

let result = json.map(({code3, asset}) => ({code3, asset}));

console.log(result);
```

This might be confusing at first, so let's see how it works:

- The `.map` method creates a new array with the output from the function on each element in the previous array.

  - Example:

```js
let nums = [0, 1, 2, 3];
let add1 = n => n + 1;

// The following two statements are equivalent:
nums = [add1(num[0]), add1(num[1]), add1(num[2]), add1(num[3])];
nums = nums.map(add1);
```

- Object destructuring is the way that we get the input from the arrow function. It's a bit hard to explain, so perhaps this article will guide you through it:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
- Lastly, we have object shorthand properties. This is how we return the result from the arrow function. If you have a variable with the same name as the property of an object and the same value as the value of that property, you can add it to the object without specifying the value.

  - Example:

```js
let a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
let o = {a, b, c}

// o = { a: 'foo', b: 42, c: {} }
```

Hopefully putting these parts together is intuitive by itself.