# How to fetch particular data from array of objects and store in new array in js (vue js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I am having this array of object

```
let detail : [ 
       0: {
            Code: "Code 1"
            Price: "0.00"   
          },           

       1: {
            Code: "Code 2"
            Price: "9.00"   
          }
]
```

I want to store the price in an array(for eg: result) so that I can merge it with another existing array of the object(for eg: alldetail)

```
result = [
    0: {
          Price:"0.00"
       },
    1: {
          Price:"9.00"
       },   
]
```

Comment: The snippet above is not a valid JS code. Assuming, that `detail` is an array of objects, you can get result by having `let result = detail.map(item => ({Price: item.Price}))`

Comment: You can use the answers shown here: [how to map more than one property from array of object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53718887)

Comment: Yes, you are right but I didn't look at the map function before now it working with the map function. Thank you @EugeneKarataev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `map()` method which creates a new array filled with the results of the provided function executing on every element in the calling array.

So, in your case, you'll return an object with the key Price and the value will be the current object with the value of it's Price property.

```js
let detail = [ 
        {
            Code: "Code 1",
            Price: "0.00"   
          },           

       {
            Code: "Code 2",
            Price: "9.00"   
          }
];

let result = detail.map(current => {return {Price: current.Price}});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: One more problem I am having, what if the Price is a array of object. How to access that key value? @RanTurner

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of objects.

```js
const detail = [ 
  { Code: "Code 1", Price: "0.00" },           
  { Code: "Code 2", Price: "9.00" }
];

const result = detail.map(({ Price }) => ({ Price }));

console.log(result);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).