# How to find just first child element in array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find first child element in array and just return it.
Here is problem because here is few children elements and i need loop thought each and return every first children element.

Example of array:

```
let allItems = 
[{  id: 1 , 
    name: 'Test 1' ,
      children: [
       id: 12,
       title: 'Child element'
    ]
},
{  
    id: 2 , 
    name: 'Test 2' 
}, 
{  
    id: 3 , 
    name: 'Test 3',
    children: [
    id: 12,
    title: 'Child element',
       children: [
         id: 123,
         title: 'GRAND Child element',
      ]
    ]
}]
```

What's the problem here? Since there can be many children elements, do I need to find a parent for each of those elements?

After looping i need array to be:

```
[{  id: 1 , 
    name: 'Test 1'
},
{  
    id: 2 , 
    name: 'Test 2' 
}, 
{  
    id: 3 , 
    name: 'Test 3'
}]
```

Wihout children elements.

What I am try:

```
allItems.map(item => item).filter(filteredItem => !filteredItem.children);
```

But this is no return me good results

Comment: So, are you trying to get the child elements or the parent elements?

Comment: just all parent elements

Comment: Based on your expected output, it looks like you just want to grab all keys from your "parent" objects without the `children` key? Possible duplicate of: [how to map more than one property from array of object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53718887)

Comment: _"How to find just **first child element**"_, _"I need to find **first child element** in array"_, _"here is few children elements and i need loop thought each and **return every first children element**"_ - Then why _"just all parent elements"_? And how does the expected output fulfill these contradicting "requirements"

Comment: agree with @NickParsons. perhaps is there a difference in concepts about what the first child element is?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output, here is my solution.

Also note, that you had missing curly braces with your children.

See you modified snippet below:

```js
let allItems = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test 1',
    children: [{
      id: 12,
      title: 'Child element'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test 3',
    children: [{
      id: 12,
      title: 'Child element',
      children: [{
        id: 123,
        title: 'GRAND Child element',
      }]
    }]
  }
]

console.log(allItems.map(item => {
  return {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is a nice way to achieve what you're looking for

```js
let allItems = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test 1',
    children: [{
      id: 12,
      title: 'Child element'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test 3',
    children: [{
      id: 12,
      title: 'Child element',
      children: [{
        id: 123,
        title: 'GRAND Child element',
      }]
    }]
  }
];

const res = allItems.map(x =>  {
  const {id, name} = x;
  return {id, name};
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -4):

Use these propertys for call first child:
`.firstchild`==>this property calls first Node
`.firstElementChild`==>calls first element

Comment: this is not HTML

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).